# Join two tables using another table in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three MySQL tables: `app`, `app_metadata` and `ecosystem`.

app table structure is:

```
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field          |Type        |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id             |bigint(20)  |NO  |PRI|NULL   |auto_increment|
|name           |varchar(255)|NO  |   |NULL   |              |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

app_metadata table structure is:

```
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field          |Type        |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id             |bigint(20)  |NO  |PRI|NULL   |auto_increment|
|app_id         |bigint(20)  |NO  |MUL|NULL   |              |
|tag_name       |varchar(255)|NO  |   |NULL   |              |
|tag_value      |text        |NO  |   |NULL   |              |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

ecosystem table structure is:

```
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field          |Type        |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id             |bigint(20)  |NO  |PRI|NULL   |auto_increment|
|name           |varchar(255)|NO  |   |NULL   |              |
+---------------+------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

I would like to join `app table` with `ecosystem table` using the `tag_value column` and `tag_name column` (only when its value is **ecosystem_id**) from `app_metadata table`.

This is the code which I tried to implement this use-case, but it does not generate the expected result.
Actual result:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "EXAMPLE",
      "appMetadata": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "tagName": "ecosystem_id",
          "tagValue": "1",
          "appId": 1,
          "ecosystem": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "default"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 470,
          "tagName": "vcalmic",
          "tagValue": "2",
          "appId": 1,
          "ecosystem": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "dc/ed1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "EXAMPLE",
      "appMetadata": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "tagName": "ecosystem_id",
          "tagValue": "1",
          "appId": 1,
          "ecosystem": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "default"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 470,
          "tagName": "vcalmic",
          "tagValue": "2",
          "appId": 1,
          "ecosystem": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

OR this one

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "EXAMPLE",
      "ecosystem": {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "default"
       },
      "appMetadata": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "tagName": "ecosystem_id",
          "tagValue": "1",
          "appId": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 470,
          "tagName": "vcalmic",
          "tagValue": "2",
          "appId": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
Models.ecosystem.hasOne(Models.appMetadata, { foreignKey: 'tagValue' });
Models.appMetadata.belongsTo(Models.ecosystem, { foreignKey: 'tagValue' });

const options = {
  where: { accountId },
  include: [
    {
      model: Models.appMetadata,
      include: [{ model: Models.ecosystem }],
    }
  ]
};
const apps = await Models.app.findAll(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add a required: false, add a where clause for tagValue both inside the 'include' object. This way it brings the ecosytem when the value is 1.

```js
Models.ecosystem.hasOne(Models.appMetadata, { foreignKey: 'tagValue' });
Models.appMetadata.belongsTo(Models.ecosystem, { foreignKey: 'tagValue' });

const options = {
  where: { accountId },
  include: [
    {
      model: Models.appMetadata,
      include: [{ model: Models.ecosystem, required: false, where: {tagValue: 1}}],
    }
  ]
};
const apps = await Models.app.findAll(options);
```

Comment: I have got an error that the column `tagValue` does not exist in `ecosystem table`. My use case is to include ecosystem when `tagName='ecosystem_id' and tagValue=ecosystem.id`